# When to bind to attributes that populated with kv-file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

**test.kv**

```
<RootWidget>:
    test: test

    Label:
        id: test
        text: "some"
```

**test.py**

```
class RootWidget(Widget):
    test = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # 1:
        print(self.test)  # None

        # 2:
        def after_tick(*args):
            print(self.test)  # Label object
        Clock.schedule_once(after_tick, 0)

        super().__init__()
```

If I'll try to bind something to `self.test` directly inside `__init__` (*1*), I would get `AttributeError` since kv rules aren't applied yet and `self.test is None`. Possible workaround would be to bind to attribute after first event loop iteration (*2*).

This solution seems to be duct tape. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know 3 other ways.

First, make the `after_tick` a method and execute it in init:

```
class RootWidget(Widget):
    test = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.delayed_init()

    @mainthread
    def delayed_init(self):
        print(self.text)
```

Second, use a built-in method that is always executed after the first loop frame:

```
class RootWidget(Widget):
    test = ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_widget(self, widget, index=0):
        super().add_widget(widget, index)

        if widget.__class__.__name__ == 'Label':
            widget.text = self.test.text
```

This is useful if you have a lot of same type widgets to bind.

Third, use a property's `on_x` callback:

```
class RootWidget(Widget):
    test = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_test(self, *args):
        print(self.test)
```